# Is there any way to type characters in the browser URL in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm looking for a way to type in strings in the browser URL bar without sending the return key. I just want to show the strings there because there is no other place to add my own string descriptions to the window.

However, I could not find any way to locate the address bar and type in something. The only way to get something about the address bar is driver's *current_url* attribute, but it just returns the current URL.

Is it possible to get the address bar and type in something on Selenium?

I use Chrome driver and the versions are Python 3.7 and Selenium 3.141.0 on macOS Mojave.

---

The reason I want to show it is because I must choose and save an image on the browser window, but at the same time I need my description to choose which image to save. It is very tedious to go to Terminal output and read the description and then go back to the browser to choose the image, and that's why I want to show it on the address bar.

Comment: I don't think you can do that no.  There are other options like sending keys to the browser to select the address bar then sending keys for the url, but that wouldn't be done w/selenium

Comment: You are wanting to type text into the URL bar to label the picture? Have you considered adding the text to the name of the screenshot? You could also edit the screenshot after it's saved to disk and add the text. You could add the text to the metadata of the picture, etc.

Comment: @JeffC I want to choose and save an image based on the content of the description manually, though it would be nice if Selenium can wait for my action and save them to the disk automatically (which I think is not possible, as far as I know).

Comment: So you are browsing a site that contains a number of images and you want to save an image based on the description on the page? I'm confused because this seems like a completely different question (in the comments) than what's currently in your question. This sounds like it may be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please edit your question and describe the problem that you are trying to solve rather than the problem you are having with the potential solution you have chosen to investigate.

Comment: @JeffC Exactly, though the description is what I will prepare. It's better to show the description on the address bar, instead of going back and force between Terminal and Selenium browser.

Comment: OK. So edit your question and update it with a more clear description of what you are trying to do. A link to the site would be ideal but if you can't provide one, at least provide the relevant HTML for a picture and it's description. If the description of the image is on the page, why are you wanting to put it in the URL box? Isn't it already visible? You could always add an element to the page that contains the description if you are OK with editing the page.

Comment: @JeffC I'm not sure what you are confused, but the process is: I want to choose and save an image on the browser window, but I need my description to choose which image to save. However, it is very tedious to go to Terminal output and read the description and then go back to the browser to choose the image. That's why I want to show it on the address bar.

Comment: How is the script going to choose an image based on a description in another app? You haven't described any of that. I took from your comments that the image description was on the page itself.

Answer (score 1):

There Is No Way To Type Into The Search Bar Without Importing Another Library But If You Want To Search For Something You Can Use driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+Search Query)

Example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q="+SEARCH QUERY)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is how do I type in the browser URL box without navigating to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built into functionality of python to achieve this.
Here's a list of the sendkeys commands you can use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/windows-scripting/8c6yea83(v=vs.84)

```
import win32com.client as comctl
w = comctl.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')

# Switch to Chrome
w.activate('Chrome')
# Crl+L to activate address bar
w.sendkeys('^l')

w.sendkeys('whatever string you want to show up in address bar here')
```

Comment: That one is not so easy.  I'd suggest googling 'send keys python mac' there are a few ugly solutions, but nothing nearly as graceful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use driver.get and add a bookmark for your note....

```
driver.get("https://yourwebsite.com/yourwebpage.htm#" + yournote)
```

You could also execute a javascript to change the page's title, or add a div along the top of the page.

Comment: Doesn't this send a new request?

Comment: I think it will, yes, but you'll be at the same page.