# Enter text into the Chrome's address bar via Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

is it possible to enter a text to the address bar in Chrome with Selenium? I would like to resolve domains and get the final URL. E.g. enter freshfruits.com resolves https://www.freshfruits.com.

Comment: You may be able to access the full URL via `window.location.href` using `driver.execute_script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium does not support sending keys to the browser address bar, unfortunately.

Someone suggested a solution with `win32com.client` library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222500/is-there-any-way-to-type-characters-in-the-browser-url-in-selenium)

Haven't tried it myself as I haven't been faced with this situation. The idea is you may need to consider workarounds, as this is outside the scope of Selenium.

Comment: Do you perhaps know whether it's possible with PupeeterJS?

Comment: Sorry Matija, no idea if it can be done in PuppeteerJS. Do you REALLY need to enter just example.com? A rough idea: can't you construct the input url as 'https://'+'example.com' and see if it resolves to https:///www.example.com or not? You can retrieve the current url with Selenium using `driver.current_url` (if I remember correctly) and compare that to the input url.