# How to imitate URL typing and ENTER clicking on Chrome with Selenium and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using `Selenium` & `NodeJS` to automate download tests on `Chrome`.

I noticed that `Chrome's` download protection behaves differently when clicking a link or redirecting to URL automatically vs actually typing the URL in the address bar and clicking ENTER (Chrome protection doesn't mark some files as blocked when actually typing the URL).

What I tried till now and still got blocks for some files:

1. `driver.get(url)`
2. `driver.executeScript` to redirect to the url
3. `driver.executeScript` to create A element and clicking on it.
4. opening a new tab and then `driver.get(url)`

Is there a way to imitate the address bar typing and ENTER clicking with `Selenium`?

Comment: Is your goal to check if a file is blocked or are looking for a workaround to download a blocked file ? As far as I known there's no way to imitate URL typing and ENTER with selenium.

Comment: You can try to imitate it like selecting the browser address bar using the shortcut `Ctrl + L` and then use the `sendKey` method with some delay. Also, if you noticed that the browser behaves differently and it's because of the browser's download protection then maybe it makes sense to disable it in the automation.

Comment: @FlorentB. the point is to check if file is blocked but I saw a difference between typing the name of the file in the search bar and clicking a link. (first one doesn't show blocking, and the second does)

Comment: Are u using Python or Java?

Comment: @EdoardoRosso NodeJS but I can do python/java as well.

Comment: I've searched a lot to answer your question. It seems like the only way you can do it is with something similar to the Robot java class. Selenium can't do it.

Comment: @AviL did you check the redirection when you click the link? if there is redirection then open the redirected url by typing or using js injection. would be great if you can give me the url to check. Second the efficient way to check the file is blocked or not , hit the actually target url through any rest client , rather than doing it through browser

Comment: Tanuj, no redirection is happening. I also checked the final url, it's always chrome block unless I actually write the URL in the address bar. and regarding rest clients, I think it won't help since I'm checking in checking specifically if chrome blocks the file and no other clients/browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not support sending keys to the browser address bar, unfortunately.

Someone suggested a solution with win32com.client library for Node.js [here](https://github.com/idobatter/node-win32com)

I haven't tried this but found a similar question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398942/9313676) thread.